# Why can I call a subclass method with a superclass pointer in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, methods, subclass, superclass, derived-class

I have two classes, `Food` and `Nacho`. `Food` is `Nacho`'s super class.

```
Food *junk = [[Nacho alloc] init];
```

is valid as long as I call `Food`'s methods, right?

But how come that `Food` pointer can call one of `Nacho`'s methods (which is defined as an additional method in the subclass)?

- fixed , removed 'NS' prefix from class name.

Comment: Side note - I know this is an example but it would actually be a bad OO design to have the `NSSon` class extend the `NSMom` class. A "son" isn't a specific kind of "mom". `NSSon` and `NSMom` would probably share a common base class though.

Comment: I see your point , they are not actually sharing something like Person and Student but thanks for comment :)

Comment: Another note: the `NS` prefix is reserved by Apple. Apple advises prefixing your own class names with three or more letters. See [Programming with Objective-C](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/DefiningClasses/DefiningClasses.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it isn't really an `NSMom` instance, so you can call it at runtime because the `NSSon` instance does implement the method. At compile time you do need to do something to tell the compiler that it shouldn't check the type (or that it should trust you).

Aside - don't prefix your own classes with 'NS' in real code. Sooner or later you'll get a clash with an Apple class.

Comment: I see your point. Even though the pointer type is defined as NSMom, the instance itself is NSSon so it can call NSSon's method. Thanks :)